# Comparison of mapping solutions for mobile devices

Tags: google-maps, maps, openstreetmap, mapbox, tomtom

We are trying to build a generic solution for our mapping needs for iOS and Android (native as well as hybrid) where we need the capability to switch between the different mapping solutions provider as per customer needs.

The ones that we have seen are -

- Google Maps
- Maps with me http://mapswith.me/en/api
- Tom Tom http://developer.tomtom.com/products/Android_SDK
- MapBox https://www.mapbox.com/tour/

etc.

So we want to know what an all are the parameters we can make generic E.x. latitude, longitude, zoom etc.

and the methods that might be common say for placing of markers and overlays etc.

Can anybody please share there experience on the same.

Comment: I'm sorry but in one sentence, what is your question?

Comment: i want to know the common parameters that i can make generic so that i can make them work across different mapping solutions...say if i mention latitiude and longitude will it very across different mapping solutions...does that make sense ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to check the source of existing Webmap Solutions (OpenLayers, Leaflet, ...) or [GIS](http://www.osgeo.org/) / [OSM](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Frameworks) / .... frameworks and get ideas for your architecture.

Usually you have modules for the following aspects:

- multi CRS / projection
- vector primitives
- vector/raster layers
- basemap protocols and providers
- routing, geocoding, .... extras
- ...